# Jenkins Internationalization (I18N) testing tools/plugin?

Tags: testing, plugins, internationalization, jenkins

Does anyone know of any good internationalization testing tools or plugins that can be automated and triggered by jenkins?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What language/technology are you referring to? I could answer with FindBugs (Java, programming language), FxCop and Globalyzer but the answer depends on particular technology. Either way be prepared for less than satisfactory results.

Comment: Yes for the java programming language, FindBugs is a good tool but not much in the area of checking internationalization. Globalyzer seems like a good alternative. Are there any free/open source tools?

Comment: Very good question. From my experience the answer is unfortunately no. I cannot recall if PMD has some I18n rules.  
On the other hand, I am not so surprised that not so many tools exist. And the ones that actually do something useful are not free. If you come to think of it, it is sometimes pretty hard to detect a defect. For example how would you detect concatenations? Especially in various UI Frameworks? Simple regular expression won't do the trick :(

Answer (score 0):

Lingoport's Globalyzer  ( http://www.lingoport.com/globalyzer  ) is a tool which does static code analysis to identify internalization issues and help mitigate them. It run the analysis in two modes, interactive with a UI, or from the command line. 
The command line can be integrated in a continuous build environment. There is configuration work to adapt how the static analysis is performed on specific projects by languages (Java, JavaScript, etc.) and tune what should be identified and what should be filtered, as it is different for each project.
See http://www.globalyzer.com/gzserver/help/commandline.htm and related help files may give you a more in-depth answer to your question.